# Can't fetch data from python request response

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, python-requests

I'm new to Python, I'm using "requests" to send a post request in api endpoint
and the response I get like this:

```
{"success":true,"data":4503615,"message":"Thanks","lid":""}
```

and my code like this :

```
    import requests

para1 = {'username': 'xxxx' ,'password': 'xxx'} 
req1 = requests.post('https://testpy.com/login', data = para1)
print(req1)
```

the response I got is similar to dictionary type except the **"success":true**, I just want that **"data":4503615** numbers in a new variable. I tried to fetch that like this

```
import requests

    para1 = {'username': 'xxxx' ,'password': 'xxx'} 
    req1 = requests.post('https://testpy.com/login', data = para1)
    qq = req1.text
    cc = qq["data"]
    print(cc)
```

But it didn't show the number, Is there any way to get that number?
Thanks

Comment: As long as the request gives back a valid json structure, you can do `cc=req1.json()['data']`

Comment: Thanks a lot @Stephen it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `req1.json()` instead of `req1.text`, it parses the text of the response to a dictionary you can use in the way you describe above.

So replace

`qq = req1.text`

with

`qq = req1.json()`